# Get Opus Headers for Ogg

Tags: ios, ogg, opus

I have this example of getting the initial header information from Vorbis for Ogg Stream:

```
ogg_packet header;
ogg_packet header_comm;
ogg_packet header_code;

vorbis_analysis_headerout(&vd,&vc,&header,&header_comm,&header_code);
```

How can I get this header information from Opus with libopus?
There's some information [HERE](http://www.opus-codec.org/docs/opusfile_api-0.1/group__header__info.html), but I can't figure out how work with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ogg Opus has only two header packets: the ID header and comment header.  See [the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7845#section-5) for details on their contents.

If you are *reading* an Ogg Opus file with the [opusfile](https://opus-codec.org/downloads/) library, it processes the packets for you (including the header packets).  The various functions that you linked to are used to get information from the headers that were processed.

If you are *writing* an Ogg Opus file, you can use the [libopusenc](https://opus-codec.org/downloads/) library and it will take care of writing the headers for you.  As of version 0.2, the opusenc program in the [opus-tools](https://opus-codec.org/downloads/) package uses libopusenc.  If for some reason you want to format and write the packets yourself using the ogg library directly, you could take a look at the older 0.1.10 version of opusenc, when it did this itself; look for the comment `/* Write header */` in [opusenc.c](https://gitlab.xiph.org/xiph/opus-tools/blob/v0.1.10/src/opusenc.c#L847) and the call to [`opus_header_to_packet()`](https://gitlab.xiph.org/xiph/opus-tools/blob/v0.1.10/src/opus_header.c#L219) to format the ID header.